# A question based on location of roots using information about derivative at some points

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots

I am trying some questions asked in masters of mathematics exam of my university and I was unable to solve this particular problem.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be twice continuous function with $f(0) = f(1) = f'(0) = 0$. Then which one of the following is true:

1. $f"$ is zero function.
2. $f"(0)=0$.
3. $f"(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0, 1)$.
4. $f"$ never vanishes.

Options 1., 2. and 3. can be negated by taking $f(x) = x^{2} \cdot (x-1)$.

Can anyone please tell how to rigorously prove $3$rd option?

Comment: Do you mean _twice continuously differentiable_?  Additionally, a user with your reputation should know that [properly formatted questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) makes for better searchable and readable questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $f\in C^2$, i.e. $f$ twice continuously differentiable.  Recall Rolle's theorem

*Hint*:

> Apply it twice.

**Details if you really want to not work**:

> First for $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and we have some $c_1\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(c_1)=0$.  Then for $f'\colon[0,c_1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and you have option (3).